# From Parent ID, dynamically derive child's lookup field name/token

Tags: apex, describesobject, sobjecttype, sobjectfield, dynamic-sosl

I'm trying to save a new record dynamically, but I'm having a problem with a lookup field. For instance, I'm able to get the parent object with the id.

```
Id relatedID = '<someId>';
SObjectType parentObj = relatedID.getSobjectType();
```

But let's say as ab example, parentObj = Supervisor__c and the object I need to insert is Employee__c. The field name on for the lookup on Employee__c to Supervisor__c is called Manager__c (which I want to get and set dynamically). How can I get and set that field name with an insert? I know getReferencedTo() will return the object, but not sure how to go from the object to the field set it with dynamic dml.

This works, but it's rather ugly and I'm sure I'm missing something and it can be simplified.

```
Id relatedId = '<some id>';
SObjectType supervisorType = relatedID.getSobjectType();
SObjectType employeeType = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('Employee__c');
SObject employee = employeeType.newSObject();

Schema.DescribeSObjectResult objSchema = Employee__c.sObjectType.getDescribe();
Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = objSchema.fields.getMap();
for(Schema.SObjectField sfield : fieldMap.Values()) {
    if (sfield.getDescribe().getReferenceTo().size() > 0) {
          if (sfield.getDescribe().getReferenceTo()[0] == supervisorType) {
              employee.put(sfield.getDescribe().getName(), relatedId);
              System.debug(story);
              break;
          }
    }
}
```

Comment: if I understand you correctly, you have a field token (`Manager__c`) on the `Employee__c` object. The value of the that field has to be the ID value of the parent `Supervisor__c` object. So, the apex is simply `employeeObj.put(managerFldToken,idValOfSupervisor)`

Comment: @cropredy Yes, but if I understand correctly, that still leaves me with my original problem. I edited my original post with what works, but there must be a way to simplify it.

Comment: `employee.put(sfield.getDescribe().getName(), relatedId);` can be `employee.put(sfield, relatedId);` but I gather that what you're trying to simplify is avoidance of the loop. The issue is that a given child object can have multiple lookup fields to the same parent object and hence knowing the parent object Id doesn't give you enough info to identify the foreign key field in the child (Employee).  You have to know the relationship name to identify the appropriate child lookup field

Comment: @cropredy Thanks. I may be better off just creating a custom map with the object as the key to return the field I need. What I have is an example. Basically, the real page has the one object that has 5 lookup fields, but only 1 will be set and saved depending on a selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand the question, for a given child sObject and a given parent (lookup) object's ID, how do you locate the child object's lookup field name or token?

In your example,

`Employee__c` has several lookup fields to several parents. If you have some `parentId`, you can easily get the SObjectType of the parent with `parentId.getSobjectType()` but what is the corresponding fieldname/token in `Employee__c`?

There's no way to derive this dynamically from the describe information reliably because a given child SObject can have multiple lookup fields to the same parent SObject.

A classic example of this in `Opportunity` wherein I often see folks adding lookup fields to key `Contact`s such as `BillToContact__c` and `ShipToContact__c` (rather than using `OpportunityContactRole` which has some challenges for other reasons)

If you had an Opportunity and an ID of some Contact, which of the two Opportunity lookup fields to Contact do you try and set with the `someContactId`?

You can't, because it is the relationship name that tells you which lookup field to use and the relationship name can't be derived from `someContactId`

As you stated in your comment, in a limited application wherein you guaranteed that there were never multiple lookup fields to the same parent, you could build a map of:

```
map<SobjectType,SobjectField> parentTypeToChildFldTokenMap
```

and then you could look up the field token of the child object with:

```
SobjectField fldToken = parentTypeToChildFldTokenMap.get(someParentId.getSObjectType());
```

Otherwise, the application needs to know which relationship the `someParentId` participates in to ascertain the child fieldToken. Then, you would go to the parent's Describe result and loop through the `ChildRelationship`s looking for a match on relationshipname. The `ChildRelationship` object contains the fieldtoken of the child lookup field.

Comment: Yes, this is a limited application so I went with a custom map an it working as needed. I marked this as the answer and thanks for the explanation.